# Unhandled promise rejection on SDK39 - SplashScreen

Tags: android, sdk, expo, react-native

I have migrated to SDK 39. Upon loading the react-native + expo project on production mode, expo throws the following yellow message:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No native splash screen
> registered for provided activity. Please configure your application's
> main Activity to call 'SplashScreen.show'

I have completely no idea where this error may come from. I have tried to use `AppLoading` while the screens are rendering but it has no effect.

I want to comprehend what is going on and, at least, find a way to ignore the error without compromising the app's work flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the Expo Client. Expo Team knows the issue and they will fix it on the next patch as it states [this expo thread](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10263#issuecomment-698213132).

Comment: Never got fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No native splash screen registered for provided activity. Please configure your application's main Activity to call 'SplashScreen.show' (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#-configure-android).]

https://forums.expo.io/t/unhandled-promise-rejection/44105